# сбились подсказки в vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

При наведении на локальные переменные появляется подсказка которая бесит и мешает, как её настроить, чтобы она появлялась выше строчки на которой находится переменная?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Upd: Мб это из-за плагинов? У меня вот такие:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]